# HTML Tabla Cell/ <TD> Extra Space around Text/Image Element

Tags: html, css

I am developing a simple HTML Table. And want to Match the Cell Size with the Child Element Size . eg. Image   .

As referred in the images below, the Cell size is appearing to be 30 x 33.33. However the child element size is 30 x 20.

I tried to remove the Additional spacing using Custom CSS, but no luck.
Below mentioned is the CSS used.

```css
    .ta-cb-highlight-td-75 {
      width: calc(100% - 150px) !important;
    }

    .ta-cb-highlight-td-25 {
      width: 150px !important;
    }

    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: 0;
    }

    .ta-cb-highlight-table-td {
      display: table-cell !important;
      height: 0 !important;
      width: auto !important;
      padding: 0px !important;
      margin: 0px !important;
      /* line-height: 0px; */
    }

    .ta-cb-highlight-table-img-td {
      width: 30px !important;
      padding: 0px !important;
      margin: 0px !important;
    }

    .ta-cb-highlight-table-img-ta-td {
      height: 150px !important;
      width: 150px !important;
      max-width: 150px !important;
    }
```

```html
  <div style="max-width: 600px;">Percent Blank Image Class Experiment
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:100%;border-collapse:collapse"
      role="presentation">
      <tbody>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]> <tr style="padding: 0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 1px; " height="0"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> <![endif]-->
        <tr style="display: flex; flex-direction:row;">
          <th class="ta-cb-highlight-td-75" style="background-color: rgb(0, 145, 210);">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:100%" role="presentation">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="ta-cb-highlight-table-td"><img class="ta-cb-highlight-table-img-td"
                      style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;"
                      src="./smallImage.png" width="30" height="20"></td>
                  <td class="ta-cb-highlight-table-td"><img class="ta-cb-highlight-table-img-td"
                      style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;"
                      src="./smallImage.png" width="30" height="20"></td>
                  <td class="ta-cb-highlight-table-td"><img class="ta-cb-highlight-table-img-td"
                      style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;"
                      src="./smallImage.png" width="30" height="20"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td class="ta-cb-highlight-table-td"><img class="ta-cb-highlight-table-img-td"
                      style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;"
                      src="./smallImage.png" width="30" height="20"></td>
                  <td class="ta-cb-highlight-table-td">
                    <div
                      style="text-align: start; color:#fafafa; font-weight: 400; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont; font-size: 14px;">
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                      labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="ta-cb-highlight-table-td"><img class="ta-cb-highlight-table-img-td"
                      style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;"
                      src="./smallImage.png" width="30" height="20"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td class="ta-cb-highlight-table-td"><img class="ta-cb-highlight-table-img-td"
                      style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;"
                      src="./smallImage.png" width="30" height="20"></td>
                  <td class="ta-cb-highlight-table-td"><img class="ta-cb-highlight-table-img-td"
                      style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;"
                      src="./smallImage.png" width="30" height="20"></td>
                  <td class="ta-cb-highlight-table-td"><img class="ta-cb-highlight-table-img-td"
                      style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;"
                      src="./smallImage.png" width="30" height="20"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </th>
          <th class="ta-cb-highlight-td-25">
            <div>
              <img class="ta-cb-highlight-table-img-ta-td" src="./img.png"
                style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0px; display: block; " height="150" width="150">
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Any suggestions on how to implement the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: does the image have margins? why do you have `height: 100%` on the table?

Comment: Hi @rayhatfield, I have updated the information above, there is no additional padding and margin for image

Comment: It looks like you've commented out the `line-height: 0` rule. What happens when you put that back?

Comment: Actually, the problem is - if you follow the Black image on the right, it has fixed height and width of 150px . This makes the Blue column / cell on the left to respect that width as well. If I make the Min-height = 110px then the other to rows above / below will automatically shrink to 20px height